# Bash script commands to extract lines in custom log file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to parse a linux application log file and extract lines that match a field(EXPIRYTIME:20140612230000) only when that field value is greater than a specific date(20140612).
This is a sample entry below;

```
[DATE: Fri Jun 06 00:00:05 UTC 2014] [MSISDN: 000000000000] [SPID: 0000000000000]      [SERVICEID: 00000000000] [PRODUCTID:0000000000000]  [UPDATETYPE: 3] [UPDATETIME: 0000000000000] [EXPIRYTIME: 20140612230000] [serviceAvailability:0] [durationOfSuspendPeriod:10] [channelID:2] [microbillingFlag:0] [packagePriceType:2]    [status:0] [transactionID:000000000000]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do the seconds matter?

Comment: Nevermind, the seconds do matter. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'EXPIRYTIME:\\s*' -v d="20140612" '{s=$2;sub(/\].*/,"",s)}1*s>d*10^6' log
```

you can pass shell variable to `d`, but it should be in `yyyyMMdd` format, since it will be multiplied by 1000000 later.

Comment: I need to review awk, badly! I'm going to try your solution and mine.

Comment: @Kent Please what would be the solution if I wanted to compare just the date part of the EXPIRYTIME:20140612 without the 230000? Thanks.

Comment: @ace i dont have pc rightnow, but you need play a number game. or take it as str, remove time part

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world...

```
awk '$20 > 20140612000000' logfile | grep 'EXPIRYTIME: 20140612230000'
```

Comment: Please explain your answer _in your answer_, not via comments. If you know your answer to be broken but still want to leave it, put a big disclaimer _at the top_. Your `grep` command results from a misunderstanding, I think: filtering the log file based on date range is sufficient; `20140612230000` is just a value from a sample log entry. Your `awk` command actually _does_ work, even though your number is too large (should be `20140612000000`) - it is in fact the very `]` at the end of the field that makes it work: it cause `awk` to perform _lexical_ comparison.

Comment: @mklement0 You have a strange way of being helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution that's even a tiny bit faster than [@Kent's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24084103/45375), presumably because fewer regexes are involved:

```
awk -v d='20140612' '$20"" > d' logfile
```

- `d='20140612'` passes in the cut-off date (after which log entries should be matched)
- `$20`, using `awk`'s standard field separators, is the *value* of the `EXPIRYTIME` field *including the terminating `]`*, e.g. `20140612230000]`
- `$20"" > d` performs *lexical* comparison against the date passed in; note that the concatenation with `""` - to force *lexical* comparison - is not strictly necessary here (`$20 > d` would do), because `awk` interprets field `$20` as a *string* anyway, due to the field ending in `]`. If at least *one* operand is considered a string, *lexical* comparison is performed.

Since all dates in the log entries seemingly have fixed width and a format that results in the  *same* ordering for both numerical and lexical sorting, there is no need for number conversions.

Note, however that treating `20140612` as a string and using lexical comparison means that value `20140612000000` will also match - i.e., midnight of the cutoff date will be *included*. This could easily be fixed, however.